# CV(0-9v) controlled 555 pwm duty cycle

Tags: pwm, brushless-dc-motor, 555, voltage-controlled-resistor

I'm working on a motor control project using the [DRV11873](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/slws237a/slws237a.pdf?ts=1702768184980) which is controlled by PWM duty cycle. Based on the [DRV11873 dev board](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slwu083a/slwu083a.pdf?ts=1702765622989&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Ftool%252FDRV11873EVM) I have a working circuit using a 555 for variable duty cycle using a potentiometer, but I was wondering if it's possible to switch out the pot (R6) in this circuit with a CV source (between 0-9v) to control the PWM duty cycle based on voltage? I've found some info on using vactrols or JFETs as variable resistors but seems like that wouldn't work in this case?

btw this is my first time posting here so let me know if I missed anything with formatting or anything, thanks!

[image: 555 PWM circuit]

Answer (score 1):

A 555 is not well suited to this application. You'd do better with a 25kHz triangle wave or sawtooth wave generator and a comparator.

There's a single-chip solution which might be easier, but will probably have a higher parts cost- the [LT6992-1](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/LTC6992-1-6992-2-6992-3-6992-4.pdf). It is a 5V part with output linear with inputs between 0.1 and 0.9V, and can be set via several resistors to your 25kHz PWM frequency.